# Renderer2 bind event to dynamically created element using loop

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am using Angular 4+ , `import { Component, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';`
I have successfully generated series of element:

```
    const parentList = this.renderer.createElement('ul');
    let children = '';
    for(let i=0; i<totalItem; i++) {
       children += '<li id="item'+i+'">'+item.name+'</li>';
    }
    parentList .innerHTML = children;

    this.renderer.appendChild(
       this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.wrapper'), 
       parentList);
```

Using `renderer.listen`, how do I bind click event to all created `li` throgh iteration?
My try:

```
for(let j=0; j<totalItem; j++) {
   let listener =
     this.renderer.listen(
        this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('#item'+j), 
        'click',
        (evt) => {
           this.myFunc(j);
        }
      );
}

.....

myFunc(id) {
   alert(id);
}
```

The problem is for each clicked `li` will alert the latest value of `j` after the iteration finished.
I want it to alert different `id` for each `li`.
I think the way I bind the event is wrong. Please help me.

Comment: You should be using `(click)` on `li` instead.

Comment: The event is not binded when i write (click)="myFunc(i)" in the html string

Comment: And did you sanitize this before adding it to the DOM?

Comment: There might be a better approach of doing this. What exactly are you trying to achieve here BTW?

Comment: @SiddharthAjmera I want to bind a click events to some dynamically created element to trigger a function which parameter is depending on the clicked element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your DOM is appended to DOM tree, you can query all DOM that starts with `item` id, for the same you can use `querySelectorAll` with `[id^="item"']` expression where it says collection all elements that have attribute `id`'s starts with `item`. There after loop over the collection and bind event on each element separately.

```
let listItems = Array.from(this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('*[id^="item"]'))

listItems.forEach((listItem, j) => {
    this.renderer.listen(
        listItem, 
        'click',
        (evt) => {
           this.myFunc(j);
        }
    );
})
```

Comment: You are right. I should have used querySelectorAll. Thank you